# Histograma com uma coluna de texto

Tags: r

Preciso fazer um histograma. Tenho as seguintes 3 colunas:

- L cursos oferecidos
- M vagas ofertadas
- N vagas preenchidas

Vagas ofertadas e preenchida ok, o problema é que não consigo colocar os dados da coluna L no eixo X. Cheguei a utilizar o comando, mas recebo uma mensagem de erro:

```
hist(ESCOLA$DESCSERIE, breaks=seq(from=1, to=255), main="CURSOS", 
  xlab="DESCSERIE", ylab="MATRIC")

Error in hist.default(ESCOLA$DESCSERIE, breaks = seq(from = 1, to = 255),  : 
 'x' deve ser numérico
```

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Infelizmente, esta pergunta não pode ser reproduzida por quem for tentar respondê-la. Por favor, [dê uma olhada neste link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/824/como-criar-um-exemplo-m%c3%adnimo-reproduz%c3%advel-em-r) e veja como fazer uma pergunta reproduzível em R. Assim, as pessoas que desejarem te ajudar conseguirão fazer isto da melhor maneira possível.

Answer (score 2):

O histograma é um gráfico pensado para visualizar a distribuição de variáveis numéricas pelo espaço amostral. Você pode cumprir a mesma função com informações categóricas (como deve ser a variável L - cursos oferecidos).

Criando dados  fictícios para usar na resposta

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(123)

escola <- data_frame(
  curso = sample(c("Direito", "Economia", "Estatística", "Serviço Social"), 
                  size = 100, replace = TRUE)
)
```

Para criar um gráfico de barra que ajuda a entender a distribuição das variáveis categóricas no espaço amostral com o [ggplot2](/questions/tagged/ggplot2), basta passar o `data.frame` para a função `ggplot()` e o nome da variável para a função `aes()`.

```
ggplot(escola, aes(curso)) +
  geom_bar()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]